# Разбить по категориям (сотовый номер, домашний, без номера)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, pandas, excel

В строке необходимо найти номер телефона, если сотовый, в столбце Output ячейке присваивается "с", иначе если домашний, присваивается "д", иначе "о". Существуют 2 столбца "А11" и "А55", если c "А11" еще можно что-то придумать (подсчитать через цикл количество цифр и взять начало +79 или 89 (со скобкой не понял что делать)), то с "А55" теряюсь. Проходить циклом в каждой ячейке страшно, так как строк несколько тысяч и все это может надолго затянуться. Может, имеет смысл (и есть возможность) предварительно в экселе отсечь мусорные символы какой-то формулой? Буду рад любому совету. Скидываю эксель и блокнот: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Vd7AH-tTEaQQqdZzdiS7fPnvt4wfWItz?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
ex1 = pd.read_excel('prim.xlsx')
```

Для А11 написал очень простой код:

```
import re
number = '+79603170351'
num = '+7 (884) 147-56-58'
number = ''.join(number.split())
number = ''.join(number.split("-"))
number = ''.join(number.split("+"))
number = ''.join(number.split("("))
number = ''.join(number.split(")"))
print(number)
match = re.findall(r'[78][9].........', number)
print(match)
rematch = re.findall(r'[78][0-8].........', number)
print(rematch)
c = []
if match !=c:
    print("с")
elif rematch != c:
    print("д")
else:
    print("о")
```

Comment: нет, так не пойдет. опишите алгоритм отбора номеров по категориям. в противном случае, вы решаете проблему не с того конца - решать ее придется на этапе подготовки данных.

Comment: Пытался описать алгоритм, наверное, выразился недостаточно точно. Ищем сотовый в ячейке, if: находим, то присваиваем ячейке в столбце Output  "с", конец, переходим к след ячейке, elif: находим домашний, присваиваем "д", конец, переходим к след ячейке, else: присваиваем "о", конец, переходим к след ячейке, и так до конца датафрейма.

Comment: Алгоритм отрабатывает на столбце А55, А11 - это более простой вариант, думал потренироваться сначала на нем

Comment: phonenumbers вам в помощ

Answer (score 0):

Сделал таким образом + вывел нужные номера:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools
xlsx = pd.read_excel('reg.xlsx')
c = []
for ind in range (len(xlsx)):
    if type(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A11']) is str:
        print(ind)
        b = ''.join(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A11'].split())
        b = ''.join(b.split("+"))
        b = ''.join(b.split("("))
        b = ''.join(b.split(")"))
        b = ''.join(b.split("-"))
        match = re.findall(r'[78][9]\d{9}', b)
        rematch = re.findall(r'\d{6}', b)
        if match !=c:
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "с"
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = match
        elif type(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55']) is str:
            a = ''.join(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55'].split())
            a = ''.join(a.split("+"))
            a = ''.join(a.split("("))
            a = ''.join(a.split(")"))
            a = ''.join(a.split("-"))
            a = ''.join(itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, a))
            sot = re.findall(r'[9]\d{9}', a)
            zvon = re.findall(r'd{6}?', a)
            if sot != c:
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "с"
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = sot
            elif zvon != c:
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "д"
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55']
            elif rematch !=c:
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "д"
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A11']
            else:
                xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "о"
        else:
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "о"
    elif type(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55']) is str:
        e = ''.join(xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55'].split())
        e = ''.join(e.split("+"))
        e = ''.join(e.split("("))
        e = ''.join(e.split(")"))
        e = ''.join(e.split("-"))
        e = ''.join(itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, e))
        sot = re.findall(r'[9]\d{9}', e)
        zvon = re.findall(r'\d{6}?', e)
        if sot != c:
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "с"
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = sot
        elif zvon != c:
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "д"
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A55']
        else:
            xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "о"
    else:
        xlsx.at[ind, 'Output'] = "о"
for ind in range (len(xlsx)):
    print(ind)
    a = str(xlsx.iloc[ind]['Input'])
    a = ''.join(a.split())
    a = ''.join(a.split("["))
    a = ''.join(a.split("]"))
    a = ''.join(a.split("'"))
    a = ''.join(a.split("+"))
    a = ''.join(a.split("("))
    a = ''.join(a.split(")"))
    a = ''.join(a.split("-"))
    a = ''.join(itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, a))
    xlsx.at[ind, 'Input'] = a

xlsx.to_excel("end2.xlsx")
```